# Find the next word after matching a word in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string

Want to get the first word after the number from the string **"Apply for 2 insurances**".

```
var Number = 2;
var text = "Apply for 2 insurances or more";
```

In this case i want to get the string after the `Number`, So my expected result is **"insurances"**

Comment: better will be to break the string into array and then match and once it matches(suppose array[i]) then get array[i+1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use Regular Expression to get the first word after a number, like so ...

```js
var number = 2;
var text = "Apply for 2 insurances test";
var result = text.match(new RegExp(number + '\\s(\\w+)'))[1];

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This seems not to work if a dash (-) is considered part of the word.

Answer (score 4):

A solution with `findIndex` that gets only the word after the number:

```js
var number = 2;
var text = "Apply for 2 insurances or more";
var words = text.split(' ');

var numberIndex = words.findIndex((word) => word == number);
var nextWord = words[numberIndex + 1];

console.log(nextWord);
```

Comment: @URoy I see! Take a look at my updated answer. Added a new solution that works in this case :)

Comment: Why not do `words.indexOf(number.toString())` instead?

Comment: @IamL That would also work. You just need to be careful to get only the next word after that index ("insurances"), not the entire remaining string (" insurances or more")

Answer (score 1):

```js
var number = 2;
var sentence = "Apply for 2 insurances or more";

var othertext = sentence.substring(sentence.indexOf(number) + 1);
console.log(othertext.split(' ')[1]);

//With two split
console.log(sentence.split(number)[1].split(' ')[1]);
```